# Installed rEFInd Boot Manager, it seems HD re-ogranized

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition, efi

Before I installed rEFInd, I believe there were three partitions to my Mac, disk0, disk1, disk2.

Now, when I run in the Command line

```
 diskutil list
```

This is what remains:

```
 /dev/disk0
    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
    0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
    1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
    2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.2 GB   disk0s2
    3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

I'm not sure what to think of this. Previously `/dev/disk0s2` was `Apple_CoreStorage` of a size around 499 GB. Then there was a `/dev/disk1`, which was "Apple_HFS Macintosh HD". Notice that's now disk0s2 above.

Should I worry? Thankfully I have everything saved on an external hard drive.

EDIT: If it helps, my HD used to look like the second screenshot on this web tutorial, after `diskutil list`. http://www.theinstructional.com/guides/disk-management-from-the-command-line-part-1

Comment: That's a pretty standard GPT partition layout. Looks fine to me.

Comment: @FakeName My only concern really is that "Apple_CoreStorage" seems to have disappeared. That's strange.